# the trace of difference of two bounded projection operators is an integer

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I am solving this problem about trace class operators, but I got stuck:

Ler $P$ and $Q$ be bounded projections in a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Suppose $P-Q\in\mathcal{B}_1(\mathcal{H})$ (the set of trace class operators), then $tr(P-Q)\in\mathbb{Z}$.

**Here are some thoughts that I have so far:**

(1) Use these relations: Setting $A=P+Q$ and $B=P+Q-I$, I can get the relations $AB+BA=0$ and $A^2+B^2=I$.

(2) Show that if $\lambda_0\neq\{\pm{1},0\}$ is an eigenvalue of $P-Q$, then $AM(\lambda_0)=AM(-\lambda_0)$. $tr(A)=\sum_{i}\lambda_i$, where $\lambda_i$'s are the eigenvalues of $A$.

From here, I cannot proceed further. I am new to this part of functional analysis, so this question really challenges me. Can anyone connect my thoughts together and write a rather complete proof? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let $U = im P$, $V = im Q$. Come up with orthonormal bases for $A \cap B$ for $A = U$ or $U^\bot$, $B = V$ or $V^\bot$. The entire vector space is a direct sum of these four subspaces, so the union of these four orthonormal bases forms an orthonormal basis. It's easily seen that for each $v$ in this basis, the inner product of $v$ with $(P - Q)v$ will be an integer. Thus, so too will the trace be.

Comment: Can you write more about your ideas? I don't see how you used my second thought. Thank you!

Comment: And can you notice what theorems you have used here?

Comment: @Doctor Who I am almost sure Your argument is correct, but it would be much nicer if you would elaborate on it a bit

Comment: Something like: choose an orthonormal basis according to the decomposition $\mathcal{H}=U\cap V\oplus U\cap V^{\perp}\oplus U^{\perp}\cap V\oplus U^{\perp}\cap V^{\perp}$ let $v$ be an element of this basis, explain why $\langle(P-Q)v, v\rangle\in\{0,1,-1\}$ and use $tr(P-Q)=\sum_{v\in B}\langle (P-Q)v,v\rangle$ where $B$ is the appropriate basis

Comment: Anyway +1 for the idea, $P-Q\in\mathcal{B}_1(\mathcal{H})$ should be mentioned too in order to be sure the trace is finite

Comment: @Doctor Who Can you write more in details using Peter Melech's method? I still did not figure out this on my own. Thank you.

Comment: Also did you use any of my thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment, but unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to comment so this'll have to do. The decomposition into intersections of the projections' kernels and ranges described in the previous answer unrfortunately does not exist in general. In fact, the intersections could all be empty. Take for example the orthogonal projections onto span((0,1)) and span((1,1)) in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The same can also happen in infinite dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Still not a proper answer, but a reference for one: The statement you are looking for is proved in "Why the circle is connected" by E. Effros as Lemma 4.1 (Link to the paper: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF03023772.pdf).